# Why do I get java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't find dependent libraries?

Tags: java, opencv

I wrote code using Java with OpenCV for my Face Detection program. Previously my program was able to run in my old PC. But then I tried to run my program in my new PC and I got this error. Do I need to install/include anything to solve this problem?

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   C:\Users\edaranadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\jniopencv_core7490305950243316892.dll:
>   Can't find dependent libraries

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

- Install microsoft c++ 2010 redistributable x64.
- Make "C:\opencv\build\common\tbb" as yor path in environment variables.
- Download javacv-0.1.jar and make this as your library file in your project.
- If the problem exist download cv100.dll, cvcam100.dll,cxcore100.dll,opencv_highgui220.dll from internet and copy this to system32.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install OpenCV to have the dll ;)

You will find all explanations there :
http://code.google.com/p/javacv/wiki/Windows7AndOpenCV

Comment: I already installed OpenCv and followed the instruction, yet still get same error. My PC is Windows 7. I have tried using my friend's PC, Windows XP, still same error. But, thanks for the link. :)

Comment: try to check if you can find the opencv dll on your computer. Somethng like jniopencvXXX.dll. Checks that the version of opencv you installed is the same as the library you use.