# Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1 error during mapreduce task

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hipi

On executing jar in hadoop, I get the following error:

```
16/11/04 18:32:59 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1478261728730_0005_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1478261728730_0005_01_000004
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

16/11/04 18:33:09 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
```

This is application log:

```
Native code library failed to load.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java2411 in java.library.pathopencv_java2411
```

I don't know what it mean, can anybody help with this please?

Comment: Update your post with application logs

Comment: I have updated the post..@KrishnaChaitanyaReddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing opencv on your cluster nodes.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840758/opencv-java-exception) for all the details on how to handle this.

Long story short though, you need to install opencv on your executors. You cannot really compile it into your job's `.jar` in a portable way since it's `C` and not Java code.

Update:
Note that the environment on your Hadoop executors is set by your hadoop-env.sh. So it needs to contain a line like:

`JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=${JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH}:/etc/opencv/lib`

Comment: Yes, I got to know that, I am already loading opencv native path, but somehow its not able to load it. @Armin Braun

Comment: @Mahek 3 questions then :)
1. what Version of OpenCV did you install did you install? 
2. Also did you do so on all executors?
3. How did you install it/ensure it's loaded?

Comment: OpenCV-2.4.11 and I have posted my issue regarding loading of library here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40435812/how-to-set-native-library-path-for-opencv-in-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment68119207_40435812 @Armin Braun

Comment: @Mahek see above edit, likely it's missing in your `hadoop-env.sh`